# How to find the list of servers accessed by a webpage on android?

Tags: browser, networking, stock-browser, dolphin-browser

On my desktop Firefox I can view the list of servers any given web page accesses either by checking with Firebug or by pressing "Ctrl-i" Page Info > Media. Out of the two Firebug is of course much better, it gives a detailed list in the Network panel.

How would I do something similar on android? I don't mind using another browser either, so far I haven't found anything similar on Dolphin or Firefox.

What I'm really after is getting a list of ad servers for my frequently viewed web pages so that I can block them (I rooted my phone so I can edit /etc/hosts). So if I need to use another browser is not a problem, I'd just use it once, get a list of ad servers, block them, and then go back to Dolphin (which is what I use normally).

It just seems odd that even though this feature is present in all desktop browsers it is completely missing in android browsers.

Comment: That seems like a lot of manual work. Why won't you use one of the published hosts files to block ads? Try mvps.org, or similar.

Comment: If you've just opened a single tab, that should be the same as "list of servers an app accesses" (Firefox). In that case then: [How to listen which URLs an app tries to connect](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43444/16575) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @wbogacz: it's not that much work actually. I regularly read about 2-3 news sites, each usually uses about 8-10 ad servers, so we are talking about cataloging about 20-30 domain names. And the published hosts files usually contain a lot more which seems like an overkill.

Comment: @Izzy: it looks like to me the thread you quoted only gives tips on how to obtain the IP addresses and I need the domain names.

Comment: For blocking the servers that should be sufficient as well – an entry like `1.2.3.4 127.0.0.1` blocks the server as efficiently ;) But yes, that app goes by IP.

Answer (score 1):

you need sniff packets when open one **URL** on browser,
so, use *Burp Suite*

> (with setting proxy between android device and burp proxy)

also you can use ***Wireshark*** for sniff packets and receive *send/receive packet* between Client/Server, and ,
finally receive ip's.
i hope, this help you.

Comment: I guess this method gives you the IPs only but I need the domain names exactly because in /etc/hosts I'll associate the IP 127.0.0.1 with these names.

Comment: i think this is help you : ` play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor ` but with wireshark you can get server ip.and for your job os monitor is good.but if you have any question about this scenario, reply to me.goodluck

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to get a list of servers, you can use  Adblock Plus. And you are using Firefox on your desktop,  and  Dolphin and Firefox on Android, just like I do.    Adblock Plus works a lot better because on hosts file you need the exact domain name (one with www, without www, a different country etc).

The Hosts file provides additional protection on your desktop system and is checked before anything else.  ([Blocking Unwanted Connections with a Hosts File](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm))

Since your goal is to block ads install "[Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/android)" APP on your Android from adblockplus.org;     [Adblock Plus for Android removed from Google Play store](https://adblockplus.org/blog/adblock-plus-for-android-removed-from-google-play-store), but use the first link to get it directly from adblockplus.org

To use the hosts file from mvps.org  you would need to be rooted.    Since you are rooted you would not need to use a proxy server.

For those of you, and like myself who are not rooted, you don't have access to change the hosts file, but you can use a proxy server,  the directions are within Adblock Plus, and you can check status of whether Ad blocking is active by dragging down from the top of your Android.   That is different from the color of the ABP icon on the status bar at the top, which indicates whether you have turned it ON or OFF.

The good news: on the Android version, the APP  applies to all of your browsers; whereas, the "[Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)" Firefox extension only works on Firefox desktop, and you have to install other versions or different apps on other desktop browsers.

The bad news: on Android  there is no supplementary [Element Hiding Helper for Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/),  and it would probably not be possible to make the necessary selections with access to widen/narrow a selection.
//  David McRitchie