# How to see ip addresses of game servers

Tags: google-play-games, ip-address

I want to see the ip address which the specific game connected to specific servers that i played. My Goal is to add a QOS on my router for specific game.

iv tried doing a packet capture on my android but it has alot of other none related ip addresses seen.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43448/16575). You might also wish to check the questions in the "linked" section there.

Comment: Alternatively, you can issue `netstat -np` from a terminal and `grep` for the relevant package name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen which URLs an app tries to connect](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43444/listen-which-urls-an-app-tries-to-connect)